# Why is Android Sign Out via Chrome Custom Tab losing cookies

Tags: android, android-chrome

My current Android Application uses `Chrome Custom Tabs` to both Sign In & Out.

```
androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0-alpha04
```

The longer our users are signed in the greater the chance that user Sign Out fails.

e.g. when the user has ben signed in for 60+ mins the Sign Out consistently fails

Having employed an HTTP proxy we have discovered that all the user identifying cookies are not attached to the Sign Out call.

I was under the impression that Chrome dealt with all cookies and user applications do not have authority to affect them.

How are we losing the cookies for user sessions over 60 minutes?

Is this a known issue with Chrome Custom Tabs?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried [CookieHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieHandler) and [CookieManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieManager.html)?

This may handle your cookies for session but those doesn't save your data permanently. You may need to store your cookie information in SharedPrefferences. You can check this [link](https://gist.github.com/manishk3008/2a2373c6c155a5df6326).

Comment: I do not believe you can use either of those on cookies "owned" by chrome